# TFS 2017 Release pipeline

Tags: rest, powershell, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I have made Release pipeline for deploying artefacts using TFS 2017 Update3 Release Management and I have used variable in tasks i.e. ServerUsername(1). Now I wish to change the variable(1) name to TFSUsername in Dev, QA, UAT environment. But there is large no. of tasks. Doing it manually will be very time consuming. Is there any other way out.

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple environments. Each environment allows you to specify variables, which override any variables defined in the Release scope.

So, on your dev environment, define a variable `$(UserName)`. Use that throughout the dev environment. On your QA environment, re-use the same variable, `$(UserName)`. And so on.

Comment: Hi daniel, you got me wrong...firstly we did exactly what you have said but now we are using variable group to declare variable which will be used across all environments for that we will use variable like TFSUsername. But in our tasks I have used Serverusername which i need to replace with TFSUsername but the problem is I have got like hundreds of task where Serverusername variable is used.

Comment: @AbhishekM Then look into using the REST APIs to programmatically retrieve and update your release definitions.

Comment: could you please hint me like from where to start for REST API.

Comment: @AbhishekM As with most things in our industry, the best place to start is by reading the documentation, which can be located with your search engine of choice.